# Remove unused image objects

Tags: itext

I have PDF files that are being created with a composition tool to produce financial statements.

The PDF files are around the 5000 - 10000 pages per file using global image resources to maximise space efficiences.

These statements include marketing images.   Many of them (about 3mb worth), not every particular statements uses all the images.

When I extract the PDF file using a tool that has been developed for this purpose (or if I use adobe acrobat just for testing purposes) - to extract a blank page at the start of the PDF file, the resulting extracted PDF is around the 3mb.  Auditing the space usage sees that it is comprised of 3mb of images.

Using iTextSharp (latest 5.4.4) I have attempted to iterate through each page and copy to a writer calling reader.RemoveUnusedObjects.  But this does not reduce the size.

I also found another example to use a pdfstamper and tried the same thing.  Same result.

I've also tried setting maximum compression and SetFullCompression.  Neither made any difference.

Can anyone give me any pointers for what I might do.  I'm hoping I can do it as a simple exercise and not have to parse the objects in the PDF file and manually remove the unused ones.

Code Below:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(inputFile);

iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
// step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
// step 3: we open the document

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy pdfCpy = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(document, new System.IO.FileStream(outputFile, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte cb = pdfCpy.DirectContent;
//pdfCpy.NewPage();
int objects = reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();
reader.RemoveFields();
reader.RemoveAnnotations();
// we retrieve the total number of pages
int numberofPages = reader.NumberOfPages;

int i = 0;
while (i < numberofPages)
{
    i++;
    document.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i));
    document.NewPage();

    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage page = pdfCpy.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
    pdfCpy.SetFullCompression();
    reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();
    reader.RemoveFields();
    reader.RemoveAnnotations();
    int rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(i);
    if (rotation == 90 || rotation == 270)
    {
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height);
    }
    else
    {
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
    }
    pdfCpy.AddPage(page);

}
pdfCpy.NewPage();
pdfCpy.Add(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph("This is added text"));

document.Close();
pdfCpy.CompressionLevel = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION;
pdfCpy.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Stamper example:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(inputFile);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile + ".2" , FileMode.Create))
{
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper stamper = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, fs, iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = stamper.Writer;
    writer.SetPdfVersion(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_5);
    writer.CompressionLevel = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStream.BEST_COMPRESSION;
    reader.RemoveFields();
    reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();
    stamper.Reader.RemoveUnusedObjects();

    stamper.SetFullCompression();
    stamper.Writer.SetFullCompression();
    stamper.Close();
}
reader.Close();
```

Comment: Are you saying that a single-page PDF that has no visual content contains 3MByte of images? If so, then that PDF wasn't created correctly. Also: `RemoveUnusedObjects()` only removes unused objects. If the images are still there after calling the method, the images are probably 'in use', but 'not visible'.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I assume those image streams are named and referenced from the resources dictionary of the page (and, therefore, not removed by `RemoveUnusedObjects`), but these named resource are not used in the page content stream.  @ user3035189 Can you verify this?

Comment: @mkl yesthe images are named and referenced.  While they are not used for the particular page that has been extracted - they are used within the entire PDF file.

If I perform a a PDF optisation within Adobe Acrobat - it will remove these object as they are not part of the visible page.

Comment: Essentially you ask for a `RemoveUnusedResources` method as preparation for `RemoveUnusedObjects`. This is not yet present in iText(Sharp) but it is feasible making use of customized parser package classes. There are not only page resources but also form xobject, pattern, and annotation resources. Furthermore resource dictionaries may be shared. A complete solution, therefore, means quite some work...

Comment: So I assume I'd need to go through a method as described in the following (only found this today it didn't show up yesterday) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566896/itextsharp-splitted-pages-size-equals-file-size)

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that's the way to go for you.

Comment: Have you got a link where I can see some sample code for parsing the objects?

Comment: @dcole Well, most prominent is the parsing in the parser package; simply take any decent iText text extraction sample (i.e. one which resorts to the classes of that package) and debug into it. Another sample is the OCGParser/OCGRemover in the itext extra classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy` instead of `PdfCopy`.

For me it decreased a PDF with a size of ~43MB PDF to ~4MB.