# iTextSharp Parsing PDF Objects with a view to removing those not in use

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

As per question [Remove unused image objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210488/remove-unused-image-objects)

I was told I'd effectively have to parse a PDF file, take note of the global object names, then remove those not in use.

I would not have even an inkling of where to start.

I was having a look in VS2010 local viewer and I could see in a page there was an array called Matrix.  This seems to contain the XObjects in use in the page.  But Matrix does not seem to be a property that the API allows.

I also found in my reader an xrefObj array, which seems to be every object.  WHen looking at the XObjects i found a number of PRStream objects which corresponded in size to teh actual images.

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary dictionary = reader.GetPageN(i);

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage page = pdfCpy.GetImportedPage(reader, i);


iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary res = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary)iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetPdfObject(dictionary.Get(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.RESOURCES));

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary xobj = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary)iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetPdfObject(res.Get(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.XOBJECT));

foreach (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName name in xobj.Keys)
{
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfObject obj = xobj.Get(name);
    if (obj.IsIndirect())
    {
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary tg = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary)iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj);
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName type = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName)iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetPdfObject(tg.Get(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.SUBTYPE));
        if (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.IMAGE.Equals(type))
        {
            int XrefIndex = Convert.ToInt32(((iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference)obj).Number.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfObject pdfObj = reader.GetPdfObject(XrefIndex);
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStream pdfStream = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStream)pdfObj;
        }
    }
}
```

This block, seems to give me the entire catalog of resources - as opposed to the specific used ones on the page.

So I guess what I'm asking for is:
-How can I match what is actually in my PDF file (I assume I make a list of all the ObjNum) references on each actual page of my File against the master list that is held in the reader.
-Remove all references that are not kept in my references list and save in place (this is a temporary file so in place would be fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

So to identify the images on the page, I used a PdfReaderContentParser.

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser parser = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
MyImageRenderListener listener = new MyImageRenderListener();


while (i < numberofPages)
{
   i++;
   parser.ProcessContent(i, listener);
}
```

The MyImageRenderListener is a new class inheriting: iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.IRenderListener

All I did was add all the names to a list that's accessible from the original class:"

```
public void RenderImage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();
    if (image == null) return;

    ImageNames.Add(renderInfo.GetRef().Number);


}
```

The I used the code posted in the original question as the basis of the master image list.