# extracting one page from pdf file using iText

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf, itext

I want to return one page from pdf files from java servlet (to reduce file size download), using itext library.
using this code

```
     try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(input);
        Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(page_number) );


        PdfSmartCopy copy1 = new PdfSmartCopy(document, response.getOutputStream());
        copy1.setFullCompression();
        document.open();

        copy1.addPage(copy1.getImportedPage(reader, page_i) );
        copy1.freeReader(reader);
        reader.close();

        document.close();

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this code returns the page, but the file size is large and some times equals the original file size, even it is just a one page.

Comment: Maybe you have a large font or a large image that is used in every page. In that case, it doesn't matter if you throw away 99 out of a 100 pages: the font and that image will still be needed for that one page and the fie size your PDF won't be reduced. You'll have to give us more info about the nature of your PDF if you want a more useful answer.

Comment: a copy of the  files is in dropbox [files link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rjkw0uageilbjm0/AAAYRLUk0j0FIk0R3KLYH1Isa/1st%20and%202nd%20Year%20Materials/Anatomy/%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%20%D9%85%D9%8A%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%86%D9%87%D8%AC%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%B8%D8%B1%D9%8A?dl=0), most of the pages is an images of papers.

Comment: I've downloaded abdomen.pdf. It's a PDF consisting of nothing but images. Why don't you extract the images and serve those? Why would need single-page PDFs if you can serve separate images?

Comment: the files that came with texts like (Special Embryology.pdf) returns small size files, but i think returning an images is the best solution since most of the files is consists of images, think you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [itextsharp: splitted pages size equals file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566896/itextsharp-splitted-pages-size-equals-file-size)

Answer (score 11):

I have downloaded a single file from your repository: Abdomen.pdf

I have then used the following code to "burst" that PDF:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("resources/Abdomen.pdf");
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    reader.close();
    String path;
    PdfStamper stamper;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        reader = new PdfReader("resources/abdomen.pdf");
        reader.selectPages(String.valueOf(i));
        path = String.format("results/abdomen/p-%s.pdf", i);
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,new FileOutputStream(path));
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

To "burst" means to split in separate pages. While the original file Abdomen.pdf is 72,570 KB (about 70.8 MB), the separate pages are much smaller:

[image]

I can not reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: but for some files like (Introduction 2013.pdf), the produced files is very large, see this link (http://2-dot-sheet-s0.appspot.com/toimage?name=Introduction%202013.pdf&page=1) the file size produced is about 12 MB which is equal to the pdf size.

Comment: I am no longer at my computer, but on my phone. If you wanted me to test a particular file, you should have said so. This will learn you to be more precise in the future.

Comment: @Ahmed In the file *Introduction 2013.pdf* you have the same problem as discussed in the question [itextsharp: splitted pages size equals file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566896/itextsharp-splitted-pages-size-equals-file-size): All pages share a single **Resources** dictionary, **4 0 R** in your case. Thus, splitting copies all resources for each page. Before splitting, therefore, you should refine the PDF to have individual **Resources** dictionaries for each page which do only contain the resources actually used on that page, cf. my answer to that other question.

Comment: That's a great answer, @mkl and it shows that some PDFs aren't created the way they should be...

Answer (score 0):

A bit more updated and a lot cleaner (5.5.6 and up) :

```
/**
 * Manipulates a PDF file src with the file dest as result
 * @param src the original PDF
 * @param dest the resulting PDF
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws DocumentException
 */
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    SmartPdfSplitter splitter = new SmartPdfSplitter(reader);
    int part = 1;
    while (splitter.hasMorePages()) {
        splitter.split(new FileOutputStream("results/merge/part_" + part + ".pdf"), 200000);
        part++;
    }
    reader.close();
}
```