# Create new single-page-PDF document from one page of a multipage PDF document

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have a PDF document which has 2 pages. I need to read the first page of this document and create a new PDF document with the read content. How would I do this using iText? So far I couldn't try anything as I don't really know how to begin. What is the best way?

Comment: why downvoting? what did I do wrong?

Comment: i'm not downvoter, but you get downvote because not show minimal effort to solve your problem by yourself first. You just want solution.

Comment: I explicitly said why I am not providing anything I tried

Comment: I think the question was closed for good reasons. The fact that you ask the question shows that no effort was done in spite of the fact that (1.) there is ample free documentation such as [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html) and (2.) the same question has been answered about 10 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382299/extracting-one-page-from-pdf-file-using-itext/28383223#28383223

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iText` classes [PdfReader](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html) and [PdfCopy](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html).

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFilename);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
if (n > 1) {
    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy= new PdfCopy(doc, new FileOutputStream(outFilename));
    doc.open();
    PdfImportedPage page = copy.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
    copy.addPage(page);
    doc.close();
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing on PdfCopy

Comment: I have adapted the answer as it wasn't entirely correct.