# iTextSharp AcroForm - multi-field not copying

Tags: c#, itext

I have a pdf with buttons that take you out to web links. I used iTextSharp to split these into separate PDFs (1 per page) per outside requirements. ISSUE: Any button that has multiple positions, lost the actions.

QUESTION: Does anyone know how to update these actions? I can open the new file, but I'm not sure how to go about using the PdfStamper to add an AA to this Annotation

So when opening the original file, you could get to the Additional Action by doing this:

```
var r = new PdfReader(f.FullName);
var positionsOfThisButton = r.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions("14");
var field = r.AcroForm.GetField("14")
var targetObject = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(field.Ref);
var kids = targetObject.GetAsArray(PdfName.KIDS);
foreach (var k in kids){
    var ko = (PdfDictionary)(k.IsIndirect() ? PdfReader.GetPdfObject(k) : k);
    var aaObj = ko.Get(PdfName.AA);
    //(aaObj is NULL in the new file)

    var aa = (PdfDictionary)(aaObj.IsIndirect() ? PdfReader.GetPdfObject(aaObj) : aaObj);
    var dObj = aa.Get(PdfName.D);
    var d = (PdfDictionary)(dObj.IsIndirect() ? PdfReader.GetPdfObject(dObj) : dObj);

    Debug.WriteLine("S:" + d.GetAsName(PdfName.S).ToString() );
    //returns S:/Uri

    Debug.WriteLine("URI:" + d.GetAsString(PdfName.URI).ToString() );
    //returns URI:http://www.somesite.com/etc
}
```

Thanks for any help.

FYI ONLY - The following is how I split the files:

```
List<byte[]> Get(FileInfo f) {
    List<byte[]> outputFiles = new List<byte[]>();
    var reader = new PdfReader(f.FullName);
    int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
    reader.Close();

    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        reader = new PdfReader(f.FullName);

        using (var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1))) {
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                using (var writer = new PdfCopy(document, outputStream)) {
                    writer.SetMergeFields();
                    writer.PdfVersion = '6';

                    document.Open();
                    writer.AddDocument(reader, new List<int> { i });
                    document.Close();
                    writer.Close();
                }

                outputFiles.Insert(0, outputStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    return outputFiles;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using the code provided in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28383223/1622493

Comment: Didn't see that version of extracting pages. That actually works perfectly. I'll update to use those. Thanks!