# How to define pdf size while splitting multi page pdf into single pdf

Tags: java, itext, pdfbox

Currently I am using itextpdf java library to split multipage pdf into single pdf.

In my case multipage pdf file is 22 MB and whenever i split into single pdf, every single pdf size will be 22 MB.

Comment: Your problem might have the same cause as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15573611/1729265) but without your PDF in question we cannot check.

Comment: hi @mkl here is the https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y9htKDL4sxOwKLa7adF-ffhdNuZ_rxLX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Indeed, that PDF has the same problematic property as the one in the linked question, a single **Resources** dictionary shared by all pages. Thus, you should proceed as described in the linked answer and the iText mailing list thread linked from the answer.